New input system is breaking when in Simulator mode
Somehow new input system, whenever I try to read the positional (Vector2) value from it returns (inf, -inf) or (inf, inf).
private Vector2 GetTouchPosition()
{
    Vector3 screenPos = input.Gesture.Position.ReadValue<Vector2>();
    if (screenPos.magnitude == Mathf.Infinity)
    {
        Debug.LogError("-------- Invalid value --------");
        return Vector2.zero;
    }
    return cam.ScreenToWorldPoint(screenPos.WhereZ(cam.nearClipPlane));
}

The problem only exist when I'm in the Simulator mode in my Unity Editor.
There is no error when I'm the Game mode, or when I upload the build on my phone or emulator.
Maybe someone knows how to fix?
Error display:

Input actions asset:

Unity version: 2022.3.44f1

Sounds more like something for Unity support tbh .. I would assume though that touchscreen would only work if your PC display actually supports it ... Not sure how far the simulator goes
